# Which books by Lem involve Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: stanislaw-lem

I'm embarrassed to admit I haven't read more Lem, but a friend who has read a great deal of his work related to me that Artificial Intelligence does appear in his works.

Which of Lem's books involve Artificial Intelligence?

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be closed. After all, how long can a list of books by one author be?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Long. Consider, for example, only the list of SF books with the name "Asimov" in the byline. "Heinlein" is another ... prolific ... name.

Comment: Lem [does have](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?166136) a ton load of books, but it doesn't necessarily mean the list has to be long. Also, @DukeZhou, you could try asking something like "How many of Lem's AI stories share a common universe?", which would give you more or less the same answer.

Comment: Well, technically this isn't a forum and your question not too precise. What to call artificial intelligence? what does it mean play a role; big role, small or only mentioned? Also he wrote lots of non-fiction, not only novels and short stories.

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for commenting.  I'm not yet familiar with this aspect of Lem's fiction, and thus the question must be broad.  Regarding "what is AI", I think that's not an issue.  I would also be interested in his non-fiction, but will likely save that for another to-be-closed question.  (Regarding this not being a "forum", that may be the case but it's also not a particularly useful site in terms of research or practical work, as opposed to the original intent of Stack as a resource for engineers.  It's a shame the Humanities sites are more concerned with parameters than usefulness.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic because it's not an open-ended list, but a finite list you can complete.  If you only count the fiction works, then Stanisław Lem hasn't even written that many books, all his stories easily fit on a short bookshelf. A complete list isn't easy to compile, but within the realm of possibilities for Sci Fi SE.

Comment: Book recommendation questions have been [off-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9957/31394) here since 2011. List questions are [off-topic only if open-ended](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2638/31394); finite, well-scoped list questions are OK. So I suggest you [edit] this question to make it sound **less like a recommendation question** ("appreciate any pointers") and **more like a finite-list question** (e.g. "which of Lem's books involve AI"). Then it's more likely to be reopened.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  Really this is for research purposes.  The mythology of AI is a subject I've been thinking about for a while.  Lem has a status that seems to exceed most writers of speculative fiction, so I believe his work to be important in this regard.  I get that the forum has rules, but it would be nice to utilize it for research on this subject.  That said, I have some ideas on how to ask more suitable questions on this subject.

Comment: The visitors in Solaris might be artificial intelligences.  It's not clear, but that's the point.

Comment: @Solaris Certainly not. They are just the stuff dredged from people's inner space. The black woman, the weird entity with the straw hat ... they are literally "visitations".

Comment: @Buzz Just re-read and, although it's true the Solarian intelligence could well be algorithmic (computational) in nature, it does seem natural as opposed to artificial.  BUT, the point you make about the visitors does seem valid--**artificial constructs created by the ocean.**

Answer (score 6):

Six of the ten [**Pilot Pirx** short stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Pirx_the_Pilot) (in the collections *Tales of Pirx the Pilot* and *More Tales of Pirx the Pilot*) use artificial intelligence as a central theme.  Pirx meets robots and ship control computers that behave in an apparently strange way.  He then has to quickly investigate what's happened, stop an impending crisis, or just wonder for the rest of his life whether he's done the right thing.

Although most of the [Ijon Tichy stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries) don't have this theme, at least the story of **Doctor Diagoras** (in the collection *Memoirs of a space traveler: further reminiscences of Ijon Tichy*) is about artificial intelligences.  The titular Doctor Diagoras is creating intelligent artificial beings, but not ones intended for some particular purpose, but without a plan to see what happens.

I haven't read [**Golem XIV**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem_XIV), but it is definitely about an artificial intelligence too.

[**The Invincible**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invincible) also counts.  Space travellers examine a planet that have strange flying insects that turn out to be miniature robots that have evolved on the planet from some technology left by a previous spaceship.

In [**Return from the Stars**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_from_the_Stars), we also indirectly witness artificial intelligence.  Robots are now performing most of the job of firefighters and similar dangerous jobs, which permits for humans no longer having to risk their lives that way.  This is important enough for the plot, even though we don't learn much specific about such robots.

A chapter of [**Imaginary Magnitude**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Imaginary_Magnitude) also deals with artificial intelligence, specifically with literature created by them.

The second chapter of the three chapters of [**One Human Minute**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem%27s_fictitious_criticism_of_nonexisting_books#Provocation_and_One_Human_Minute) (*Biblioteka XXI. wieku*) also describes a very interesting future military history with artificial intelligence taking a central role.

This is probably not an exhaustive list.

Comment: Thanks for this! *(Just wish more people read Lem so his books would show up at my local used bookstore, but I guess that's why we have the internet;)*

Comment: I finally got around to ordering the books, and found a couple more! (See my answer:)

Answer (score 3):

*Fiasco* features a powerful AI which controls the spaceship *Hermes*.

*The Invincible* counts, although of course not with its principal antagonist which is neither artificial nor very intelligent. But the *cyclops* hovering vehicle was certainly controlled by an autonomous AI.

The protagonist of *The Mask* is also apparently an AI, although we can’t be certain about her exact nature.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to b_jonas' excellent answer, there seem to be a couple recent additions:

- Mortal Engines

Blurb: *"These fourteen science fiction stories reveal Lem’s fascination with artificial intelligence and demonstrate just how surprisingly human sentient machines can be."*

- The Cyberiad

Blurb: *"Trurl and Klaupacius are constructor robots who try to out-invent each other. They travel to the far corners of the cosmos to take on freelance problem-solving jobs, with dire consequences for their employers."*